# Setting Cookie Port

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, cookies

I'm trying to set the port on a cookie in ASP.NET (code below), but I'm getting a very unusual error at runtime (below the code). Any thoughts?

```
target.Cookie = new Cookie
{
    Comment = "Test Comment",
    CommentUri = new System.Uri("http://www.tempuri.org"),
    Discard = false,
    Domain = "tempuri.com",
    Expired = false,
    Expires = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31),
    HttpOnly = false,
    Name = "TestCookie",
    Path = "/",
    Port = "443",
    Secure = false,
    Value = "Test Value",
    Version = 1,
};
```

Exception:

```
System.Net.CookieException: The 'Port'='443' part of the cookie is invalid..
```

Edit:
Sorry, I meant to mention that I also tried Port = "80" with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I never did find a good solution to this. All I wound up doing is removing the port definition. I did notice something in the W3C spec for cookies regarding ports, and if I recall, version 2 cookies don't support the specification of a port. I've tried creating the cookie without the port, then setting the port later, but with no luck. I continue to get a runtime exception of `...threw exception:  System.Net.CookieException: The 'Port'='80' part of the cookie is invalid..`

Sorry this wasn't more help...

Answer (score 3):

Bit late I know but ran into a similar issue and the Ports must be set  within comma delimited double quotes.

```
port = @"""80,8080"""
```

"*...the value must be a double-quoted string that contains port values delimited with commas.*" .Net Documentation for the [Port Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.port(v=vs.110).aspx):

Answer (score 1):

Port 443 is used for SSL connections however you have the Secure property as false. If you want to use port 443 specify Secure = true.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that I tried Port = "80" with no success, which shouldn't require Secure = true

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are setting the port of the cookie? For web requests its going to go over 80 or 443. These won't change.